# How to use a method that is in a partial class from another partial class

Tags: c#, partial-classes

I am working in an Excel file with Visual Studio and programming in C#. I added a listbox control to the sheet Seismic2D. I want to fill this listbox with information that is in the sheet FileList. The button that I am trying to program is in ribbon.

I tried to use Sis2D clase=new Sis2D(); but I got an error (There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'factory'of Sis2D.Sis2D(Factory,IServiceProvider)

In the Ribbon file...

```
public partial class Ribbon1
    {
       private void ListRefresh_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
       {
           Excel.Worksheet wsFL = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets["FileList"];
           Sis2D clase = new Sis2D();
           clase.ListaFiles.Items.Add(wsFL.Range["A2"]);
           clase.ListaFiles.Items.Add(wsFL.Range["A3"]);
        }
    }
```

In the Sis2D.cs file

```
public partial class Sis2D
```

Another thing that I tried was adding this in Sis2D

```
public partial class Sis2D
{
public void LlenaListBox()
        {
           Excel.Worksheet wsFL = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets["FileList"];
           ListaFiles.Items.Add(wsFL.Range["A2"].Value);
           ListaFiles.Items.Add(wsFL.Range["A3"].Value);
        }
}
```

But I do not know how to call this method from the Ribbon partial class.

I want to be able to interact with the ListBox, adding items and reading them.

Comment: The constructor is probably in the other partial definition of the class.

Comment: `partial class` is such a bad name.  the `partial` keyword just indicates that your class definition *may be* spread across multiple files.  Once compiled though, you got a single *complete* `class`.    ---   so Dorian, look for the file that defined the constructor for `Sis2D`.

Comment: Visual Studio creates a file for Sis2D (because is linked to a worksheet) and creates a file for the Ribbon. It is in the ribbon where I have a button that I want to fill the ListBox. The listbox is inside the worksheet manage by Sis2D. So, what I want is to call a method located in a different partial class from a class located in a different partial class.

Comment: you want to call a private method from a different class? nuff said, no?

Comment: The main idea behind this is that I add Listbox. The problem is how I can add items to it or change the items. It is almost the same than the vba listbox: it depends on the worksheet where it is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I want to say thank you for all your help and interest in helping me. I want to apologize if possibly I was not clear with my question, because I am a beginner. Finally, what I wanted, filling the ListBox inside a worksheet from Visual Studio with C#, I got it.

In the Ribbon, the code for the button is:

```
C#
public partial class Ribbon1
{
private void FL_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
   {
       Sis2D s = Globals.Sis2D;
       s.LlenaListBox();   
   }
}
```

In the sheet, the code is:

```
public partial class Sis2D 
{
public void LlenaListBox()
    {
            Excel.Worksheet wsFL = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
            ListaF.Items.Add(wsFL.Range["A10"].Value);
            ListaF.Items.Add(wsFL.Range["A11"].Value);
            ListaF.Items.Add(wsFL.Range["A12"].Value);
    }
}
```

This is all. ListaF is a ListBox added to sheet1 into a worksheet from C# in Visual Studio.
The following picture shows how the worksheet looks:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztmrX.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error that 'There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal

parameter 'factory'of Sis2D.Sis2D(Factory,IServiceProvider)' means that you only have the

following Constructor in the Sis2D class.

```
 public Sis2D(Factory, IServiceProvider)
        {
         ////////////

        }
```

If you want to access the method in Sis2D, you could add a empty constructor in Sis2D class.
Like the following:

```
   public partial  class Sis2D
   {
    public Sis2D()  //  you need to add this code
    {
    }
    public void LlenaListBox()
    {
        Excel.Worksheet wsFL = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets["FileList"];
        ListaFiles.Items.Add(wsFL.Range["A2"].Value);
        ListaFiles.Items.Add(wsFL.Range["A3"].Value);
    }
    }
```

Then you could use the following code to access the method without throwing exception:

```
public partial  class Ribbon1
    {
        public void ListRefresh_Click()
        {
            Sis2D clase = new Sis2D();
            clase.LlenaListBox();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very mucho for your answer. I did what you suggest, now the error is: **There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'factory'of WorksheetBase.WorksheetBase(Factory,IServiceProvider,string, string)**

Comment: where is the WorksheetBase class from? Because you don't give the information before, I could not how to set it. You could show all the class so that we can solve your problem wihout meeting the error.

Comment: Sorry @Jack, Sis2D is the name I gave to the file that is the class for a worksheet. I did not understand very well how VSTO works. SO, possibly, for this reason, I could not be so clear in my question. Anyway, I think the error gives no much information about the real problem. That's why I wanted to write the solution I got and is above these lines.